# Cannot create new users when submitted username contains dash symbol

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

Help me please, I'm trying to create a new user user using `class IdentityUser()`, but when I add in my `username` the `dash(-)` symbol I get an error.
How can I fix  this?

```
var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
var manager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);

var user = new IdentityUser() { UserName = aspNetUsers.Email };
IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, aspNetUsers.PasswordHash);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user manager class has a called `UserValidator`, in that class there is a property you need to alter:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store) : base(store)
    {
        this.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(this)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem. With the solution proposed by @tparnell (which is large used) nothing changes and the validation continue to fail.

I have solved with a new declaration inside the AccountController:

```
userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db));
userManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(userManager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };
```